# negation of list in python

Tags: python, list

I have a list :

```
v=[0, -0.01, 0, 0, 0.01, 0.25, 1]
```

I wanted the list to be :

```
v=[0, 0.01, 0, 0, -0.01, -0.25, -1]
```

which is the best way to do that? -v wont work.

Answer (score 18):

Using list comprehension:

```
>>> v=[0, -0.01, 0, 0, 0.01, 0.25, 1]
>>> [-x for x in v]
[0, 0.01, 0, 0, -0.01, -0.25, -1]
```

Using [`map`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) with [`operator.neg`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.neg):

```
>>> import operator
>>> map(operator.neg, v)
[0, 0.01, 0, 0, -0.01, -0.25, -1]
```

- Replace `map(..)` with `list(map(..))` if you use Python 3.x

---

Using [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> -np.array(v)
array([-0.  ,  0.01, -0.  , -0.  , -0.01, -0.25, -1.  ])
>>> (-np.array(v)).tolist()
[-0.0, 0.01, -0.0, -0.0, -0.01, -0.25, -1.0]
```